# How to register interface with Generic type in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am using WebAPI in ASP.NET Core.

This works:

```
services.AddScoped<IApiKeysService, APIKeysService>();
```

Now that the interface is returning a generic type T This does not

```
services.AddScoped<IApiKeysService>();
```

Error Using the generic type blah requires 1 type Arguments

Or this

```
services.AddScoped<IApiKeysService<T>>();
```

I get the following compile error

> type or namespace T cannot be found

How do I register it in `Startup.cs`?

> **NOTE:** I cannot use a concrete type because the interface member is a base class with generic method.

Comment: https://ardalis.com/registering-open-generics-in-aspnet-core-dependency-injection (this is a common approach in IoC containers)

Comment: use                 **services.AddScoped(typeof(IApiKeysService<>),typeof(ApiKeysService<>));**

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa but that way Im using the concrete type, which defeats the point ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Interfaces

You cannot instantiate an interface, so it is not possible to register an interface without an implementation type (whether generic or not).

However, it is possible to register types as the *concrete type* instead of an interface.

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(Foo<>));
```

Which is specified in the constructor as:

```
public MyService(Foo<ClosingType> foo)
{
    // implementation
}
```

### Open Generics

Open generics are always specified the same way in .NET: `typeof(SomeGenericType<>)`.

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IFoo<>), typeof(Foo<>));
```

If there are multiple open generic parameters, you would specify how many using commas. For example, with 2 open generic parameters:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IFoo<,>), typeof(Foo<,>));
```

Comment: HI, doesn't work I don't want to register the concreate type Foo, can it be done with just the interface ?

Comment: No, you need an implementation type of some sort. You can't instantiate an interface, generic or not.