# How to dependency-inject an interface with multiple generic types in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to dependency-inject an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface IDataReader<TInput, TOutput> where TOutput : new()
{
    Task<List<TOutput>> ExecuteAsync(TInput input, string storedProcedure);
}
```

How can I do it in the ConfigureServices function of asp.net core startup?

[image]

***Edit:***

I did this:

```
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IDataReader<,>));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to register interface with Generic type in Startup.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352434/how-to-register-interface-with-generic-type-in-startup-cs) - The answer to your question is right at the end of the answer to that one.

Comment: yes it worked  thankyou !

Comment: sorry can you please check the update ?

Comment: You can't initialize an interface. It needs a concrete type (something that implements `IDataReader`). You either pass it a concrete type as the only parameter, or as the second parameter after `IDataReader<,>`.

Comment: thankyou ! it works